# Does USB C charger support constant current feature?

Tags: usb

I want to use my existing macbook charger with uSB decoy trigger to charge 12V lithium battery. Will it destroy either the battery or the charger because of short circuit?

Answer (score 3):

**Don't do that.** And answering your question - no, it doesn't. It's a power supply unit (PSU), not the Li-Ion charger.

First of all, there is no such things as "12V lithium battery". Lithium chemistry are rated at 3.7V nominal voltage for Li-Ion, 4.2V fully charged. Something you call "12V" must be a 3 cells in series pack, rated at 12.6V fully charged, 11.1V nominal. But you don't know how it's connected, does it a have a protection circuit and/or BMS, etc.

Next, charging Li-Ion from PSU directly aren't allowed and dangerous. Li-Ion cells should be charger from specifically designed chargers for it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Yes, this is 3S2P configuration battery + BMS with over charge, over voltage and over current protection. My question was that if my macbook charger mentions 12V at 3A does that mean it will try to maintain 3A CC till battery reaches 12V and then switch to CV. I was just curious if i need a CC CV module between mac charger and my battery or can i directly plug it in.

Comment: Again - your "macbook charger" is not a charger. It's a power supply unit. It can't charge Li-Ion directly. Your macbook has a charging IC inside it. It's the one which maintains CC/CV mode, not the PSU.

Comment: 3A inscription on it is just a **maximum** current rating for it. Just like any PSU states. It's not a constant current source.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these insights.